# Is there any possible way to program a LPC1768 Microcontroller(using ULINK-ME) on macOS?

Tags: macos, development

- Hardware: Keil LPC1768 development board.
- macOS 10.14
- Flashing/Programming device: Keil ULINK-ME (USB-JTAG adapter)

I have tried the VS Code extension platformIO and mbed Studio(standalone), but none seem to find the connected board/flashing device ULINK-ME.

I have tried the same on a Windows VM running on VMware Fusion with the Keil IDE, that does all of the flashing stuff and that worked, but I would really love to get it natively running on macOS.

macOS seems not to mount the board under /dev/tty.* or anything like that, like probably Linux would do.

If any questions arise about my setup, please comment, so that I can update this post.

I appreciate any proper constructive help.
Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it is possible. After a long conversation on the platformIO community forum I was helped. here is the topic [click me](https://community.platformio.org/t/how-to-properly-set-the-upload-port-on-macos-lpc1768-board-ulink-me/9560/27)
And here is a link to a working Blinky(blinking LED) example that's doing all of the configuration stuff needed to upload it properly to the device.
[click me - Github](https://github.com/jxsl13/lpc1769_blinky_example)